# Is there a way to not to lose embedded links on PDFs while saving them as BLOB (byte array)?

Tags: spring-boot, pdf

i'm trying to save PDF files as BLOB, save it to a MySQL Database and then send it to an Android Device using REST api.

The problem is, the embedded links and connections on the PDF is lost when it is saved as BLOB. Is there a way to prevent them getting lost?

Thanks for your answers..

```
byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(path);
pdf.setData(content);

pdfService.saveDocument(pdf);
```

Comment: I don't think that this issue is a result of storing the file as a blob because a blob is just an array of bytes. Whatever you save has these embedded data removed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try base64 encoding of the content before persisting and base64 decoding of the content when you actually use it. This is to ensure that the data remain intact without modification during transport.

Here's a sample code to do so in java

```
Base64.getEncoder().encode(content);
Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedContent);
```